# Guest Access in QEMU-KVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am having trouble in accessing my Guest OS running on QEMU-KVM. However, I noticed that the Guest OS is capable of accessing Host OS easily thru telnet; basically every IP address appear in `ifconfig` is accessible by Guest OS.

The other way around, is not possible. Everytime I tried to access IP address generated from Guest's `ifconfig`, it said something about address is unreachable.

For your information, I have set up the bridge connection, so, both OSes have now IP address started with 192.168.x.x with same subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

What did I do wrong? I followed every guideline I came across the search in the internet but none is working at the moment. The host OS is Ubuntu Desktop, while the Guest is Ubuntu Server 10.10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably using a NAT'd NIC in the guest, so it can get to the 'network' but the 'network' can't get directly to it. Use a bridged connection (or similar).

Comment: can you send the output from virsh dumpxml YOUR_GUEST_NAME

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer to your other question:  http://serverfault.com/questions/260536/connecting-to-a-kvm-guest-os-in-ubuntu/260541#260541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For your information, I have set up
>   the bridge connection, so, both OSes
>   have now IP address started with
>   192.168.x.x with same subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

With you 255.255.255.0 Netmask, your host and your guest must have an address in the same subnet.

So their IP should be 192.168.**y**.x  .... where **y** is the same for both !

Comment: Thanks! I m so noob in networking >< thanks for your guidance.